# Passing an array as an argument of a function

Tags: arrays, function, arguments, ocaml

I have built a function in which the user will insert the array size and then proceed to insert its values

```
let array_builder =
  let coin = Array.make (10000) 0 in 
  let number_coins = read_int() in
  for i = 0 to (number_coins-1) do 
    let k = read_int() in
    coin.(i) <- (k);
  done;
```

The input looks something like this:

```
>3 ---> Array size

>10 ---> coin.(0)

>9 ---> coin.(1)

>8 ---> coin.(2)
```

Is there anyway to pass the array, `coin`, as an argument to another function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OCaml array are regular value and can be passed to other function without specific syntax.

Maybe you want an example. I have created a dummy function that do like your loop.

```
let rec array_filler coin_array current_index size =
  if current_index < size then
    let k = read_int() in
    let () = coin_array.(current_index) <- k in
    array_filler coin_array (current_index + 1) size
  else
    coin_array

let array_builder =
  let number_coins = read_int() in
  let coin = Array.make number_coins 0 in
  array_filler coin 0 number_coins
```

I also switched 2 lines so `number_coins` is available when creating the array (to not reserve more cell if the user don't need more than 10000)